# How can I add first map value into a second map

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger DTrigger on D__c (before insert,after update) {

    Map<Integer, String> firstMap = New Map<Integer, String>();
    firstMap.put(100, 'lokesh');
    firstMap.put(101, 'lokeshA');
    firstMap.put(102, 'lokeshB');
    firstMap.put(103, 'lokeshC');
    firstMap.put(104, 'lokeshD');

    Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondMap = New  Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>();

    for(Integer varl : firstMap.keySet()){
        String valu = firstMap.get(varl); 
        if(!secondMap.containsKey(valu)){
            secondMap.put(valu, New Map<Integer, String>());
        }else{
            secondMap.get(valu).add(firstMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the Key, and what should be the value for 2nd Map? And why are you doing it in trigger?

Comment: I am trying to learn how can we use Map into inside Map. I mean how can i add this